# mysql replace query not working

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
UPDATE post SET pagetext = replace(pagetext, 'hiiiiiii','lol')
```

But it doesn't work and I get the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''hiiiiiii''lol') FROM post WHERE' at line 1

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you setting `pagetext`? You're specifying it as a column name first, then a variable second?

Comment: its just a mediumtext

Comment: I'm thinking you didn't really post your real query.....

Comment: @JayBlanchard That's totally false. You can have a column name in the first parameter.

Comment: Urg...yep, you're right @developerwjk. That's what I get for posting while under the influence of cold medicine.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Mr. Buckley's mixture's a tad too strong. Time to dilute it with a bit of that 20yr. old Scotch ;-)

Comment: Aha! I knew I had forgotten something @Fred-ii- ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Get well soon buddy.

Answer (score 3):

> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''hiiiiiii''lol')

```
                                                        ^
```

Look close, you dont have a comma between those parameters and because of that your string becomes invalid having 2 quotation marks inside.

Comment: my query does though...

Comment: Nope it doesnt, only you think it does. If it did have the comma MySQL wasn't crazy to report it like that

Comment: It was m8. I can ready, I ain't crazy to randomly see commas.

Comment: @Shiv This answer is correct. The error message shows `near ''hiiiiiii''lol')` which means when you got the error you had left off the comma. That's it.

Comment: There is absolutely no way under the sun that you have a comma there in your actual query and mysql seems to think you don't have it. You must be overlooking a typo. Anyways there is no point trying to prove you wrong and to prove mysql correct. You mentioned your problem is resolved so let's leave it at that.

Comment: HOLY CRAP... I can read my query! It showed a comma...........

Answer (score -4):

It appears there was a problem with phymyadmin, the query is indeed correct.

Comment: The error message shows `''hiiiiiii''lol')` which means when you got the error you had left off the comma. Don't blame PhpMyAdmin for a typo.

Comment: HOLY CRAP... I can read my query! It showed a comma...........